# gfortran lib error on 64bit CentOS[ skipping incompatible libgfortran.so when searching for -lgfortran]

Tags: gcc, centos, fortran, centos7, gfortran

I installed gcc-gfortran using

```
yum install gcc-gfortran
```

But when I compile a simple program. gfortran gave the following error message.

```
[xchen@localhost develope]$ gfortran -m64 test.f90
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/libgfortran.so when searching for -lgfortran
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I checked my installed package,

```
[xchen@localhost develope]$ yum list gcc*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.lzu.edu.cn
 * epel: mirrors.aliyun.com
 * extras: mirror.lzu.edu.cn
 * updates: mirror.lzu.edu.cn
Installed Packages
gcc.x86_64                                                                                  4.8.5-16.el7                                                                                @base
gcc-c++.x86_64                                                                              4.8.5-16.el7                                                                                @base
gcc-c++-x86_64-linux-gnu.x86_64                                                             4.8.5-16.el7.1                                                                              @epel
gcc-gfortran.x86_64                                                                         4.8.5-16.el7                                                                                @base
gcc-x86_64-linux-gnu.x86_64                                                                 4.8.5-16.el7.1                                                                              @epel
```

I checked the library corresponding to gfortran

```
Installed Packages
compat-gcc-44-gfortran.x86_64                                                                    4.4.7-8.el7                                                                        @base    
compat-libgfortran-41.x86_64                                                                     4.1.2-44.el7                                                                       @anaconda
gcc-gfortran.x86_64                                                                              4.8.5-16.el7                                                                       @base    
libgfortran.i686                                                                                 4.8.5-16.el7                                                                       @base    
libgfortran.x86_64                                                                               4.8.5-16.el7                                                                       @anaconda
libgfortran-static.i686                                                                          4.8.5-16.el7                                                                       @base    
libgfortran-static.x86_64                                                                        4.8.5-16.el7                                                                       @base    
libgfortran4.x86_64                                                                              7.1.1-2.2.1.el7                                                                    @base
```

Comment: The linker can't find the 64-bit version of libgfortran.  You probably have to install an additional package. What about `gcc-gfortran-x86_64-linux-gnu.x86_64`?

Comment: I can't find gcc-gfortran-x86_64-linux-gnu.x86_64 with yum.

Comment: Simply install all 64 fortran packages you find... I was just guessing the name.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I found Blas and Lapack installed from Yum have the same problem *skipping incompatible*